# How do I share source code between services in production?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two services as shown bellow:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html:ro,cached
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    links:
      - fpm

  fpm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/fpm/Production.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/html
```

and here's the Production.dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

COPY . /var/www/html
```

The idea is that for performance & deployment concerns, I should copy source code into php-fpm image, right?

So what if in first I couldn't put php-fpm and nginx into one piece of image for scalability reason or what ever the reason is,

and as far as I know, that nginx and php both needed the source code, `How do I share it between them?`

I thought about building the nginx image and copy the source code as well, but that would be problematic if one of the copies has changed in runtime, right?

How about named volumes? copy source code into volumes and share them between services? But that's against the original idea I got above.

Simply put, I wanted to share a folder in a container with another container.

What is the best practice?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If anyone comes across this issue, well, the idea is invalid. Because nginx only needs the index.php file, aka, entry file. So it's not a problem at all. You should just copy the entry file for the nginx image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The idea is that for performance & deployment concerns, I should copy source code into php-fpm image, right?** I would say that only the static assets needed

**and as far as I know, that nginx and php both needed the source code, How do I share it between them?** You can configure Nginx to proxy the request and that way Nginx does not need to have access to the source code unless you plan to serve the static assets or php code directly with nginx

**How about named volumes? copy source code into volumes and share them between services?** This is not a scalable idea, since you need to mount the volumes to all production nodes and stored them in a shared files system such as NFS and this will slow down the application

There are more than one way to achieve this, 
1- build the docker files in the same host and update docker files to copy the files during the build time.
2- use multistage builds and copy files from one image to another

This post explains it all: https://medium.com/faun/three-methods-to-share-rails-assets-with-nginx-f39c90bb7d68

example docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: mysqld --general-log=1 --general-log-file=/var/log/mysql/general-log.log
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dummy
      MYSQL_DATABASE: rails_blog_production

  rails_blog_web:
    image: wshihadeh/rails_blog:master
    restart: always
    command: 'web'
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: mysql2://root:dummy@mysql/rails_blog_production

  web:
    build:
      context: nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: server
    ports:
      - 80:80

volumes:
  db_data:
```

Nginx: dockerfile

```
FROM wshihadeh/rails_blog:master


From nginx:latest

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN mkdir /var/www/
WORKDIR /var/www/

COPY --from=0 /application/public public/
```

app dockerfile

```
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

USER rails
WORKDIR /application

RUN bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries && \
    bundle config git.allow_insecure true && \
    bundle config set deployment 'true' && \
    bundle config set frozen 'true' && \
    bundle config set without 'development test' && \
    bundle install --quiet && \
    bundle exec rake assets:precompile && \
    mkdir tmp/pids && \
    rm -rf vendor/cache/*.gem

CMD web
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. about your suggested two ways of achieving this, the first one, as I said, I wouldn't want two services stick together for scalability reason, and the second one, the problem isn't at build time, it's that I won't be able to sync assets, logs or whatever could be changing in the run time.

Comment: But Yes! You said that ` I would say that only the static assets needed`, the nginx server only needs the php entry file and the assets. the rest just being ignored. I didn't know that!  Thank you!